# Flask unable to find templates

Tags: python, flask

My project structure is like below

```
run.py
lib/
mysite/
    conf/
        __init__.py (flask app)
        settings.py
    pages/
        templates/
            index.html
        views.py
        __init__.py
```

This is `mysite.conf.__init__`

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
```

My idea is to now import `app` to every other module to use it to create views. Here in this case there is a module `pages`.

In `pages.views` I have some code like

```
from flask import render_template
from mysite.conf import app

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

The `index.html` is placed in `pages/templates`

When I run this app from `run.py` which is like below

```
from mysite.conf import app
app.run()
```

I'm getting template not found error.
How to fix it? and why is this happening!

I'm basically a django guy, and facing a lot of inconvenience with importing the `wsgi` object every time to create a view in every module! It kinda feels crazy -- Which in a way encourages circular imports. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Try `render_template('templates/index.html')`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Flask expects the `templates` directory to be in the same folder as the module in which it is created; it is looking for `mysite/conf/templates`, **not** `mysite/pages/templates`.

You'll need to tell Flask to look elsewhere instead:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../pages/templates')
```

This works as the path is resolved relative to the current module path.

You cannot have per-module template directories, not without using [blueprints](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/blueprints/). A common pattern is to use subdirectories of the `templates` folder instead to partition your templates. You'd use `templates/pages/index.html`, loaded with `render_template('pages/index.html')`, etc.

The alternative is to use a `Blueprint` instance per sub-module; you can give each blueprint a separate template folder, used for all views registered to that blueprint instance. Do note that all routes in a blueprint do have to start with a common prefix unique to that blueprint (which can be empty).

Comment: I have some more modules like `person`. where I want to look into `person/templates` dir. how to automatically do this..

Comment: @Iamcool: either use Blueprints per module (which can have their own independent template folder configured), or don't do that. Normally you'd use subfolders of `templates/`, like `templates/person` then load `render_template('person/template.html')`.

Comment: I happened to look into Blueprints. Well its says they are not pluggable apps. If we compare with Django's apps.. how different they are?

Comment: @Iamcool: they are groupings of hook handlers, routes, static resources and templates. Flask-Admin is a blueprint, for example.

Comment: @Iamcool: They are a lot like Django apps therefor; a Django app also groups urls, views, static files and templates under a common path prefix.

Answer (score 3):

I ran in to this problem as well being brand new to Flask.

The solution for my situation was to create an `__init__.py` file in the main app directory so as to turn `app/` in to a module since, as `Martijn Pieters` pointed out, flask expects `templates` to be in the main **module** directory by default. And to restate from his answer, you can reassign the default directory when instantiating the `Flask` class, e.g. `Flask(__name__, template_folder=any/relative/path/from/app/dir/or/absolute/path/youd/like)`

A simple directory structure should therefore look like this:

```
app/
    run.py
    templates/
        sample_template.html
    __init__.py  # <---- This was the missing file in my case.
```

... where `app.py` might look like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)  # or e.g. Flask(__name__, template_folder='../otherdir')

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello world"

@app.route("/hello/again")
def hello_again():
    return render_template("hello_again.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: What's the point of the __init__.py in this case? What's included in that?

Comment: I'm sure you've worked this out by now @MrDysprosium but __init__.py is empty. However, you could put the app in the contents of app.py in the __init__.py if you wanted to. When python imports a module, the code in this init is executed. The module's directory structure is also searched recursively, and the init file is used to determine whether or not any subdirectories should be imported as submodules. As you can imagine, submodule __init__.py files are also executed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you made a mistaking spelling "template" on main folder. Just rename it

or:

do something like this (template_folder = 'the name of the folder your file belongs to')

```py
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import render_template


views = Blueprint('views',__name__,template_folder='tamplate')




@views.route('/')

def home():

    return render_template("home.html")
```